# SCEditor BBcode to HTML parsing

Tags: javascript, bbcode

Does anyone know which method or how to use the API in [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) so that it parses an input BBcode into HTML, instead of just parsing the textarea?

I am aware of [SBBCodeParser](https://github.com/samclarke/SBBCodeParser), but I require the thing to be done in JS instead of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get value http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/val/
2. Convert BBCode into HTML http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/plugins/bbcode/#fromBBCode

You can do like this

```
var val = $('textarea').sceditor('instance').val();
var result = $('textarea').sceditor('instance').fromBBCode(val, true);
//result = html code
```